# Why does my font not work in indesign?

Tags: html, css, webfonts

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(fonts/LeagueGothic-Regular.otf);
}

.header_text {
 font-family: myFirstFont;
}
```

```html
<div class="header_text">
   porman-city2live
</div>
```

Why does my font not work in in design? I want to run my fonts in th web.

Comment: Is the fonts directory a subdirectory of whatever directory the css file is in?

Comment: You are seeing now
css>style.css
font>LeagueGothic-Regular

Comment: My question was, is **fonts/** inside **css/** or not?